# Why does "python foo_setup.py sdist" error on a completely irrelevant file`

Tags: python, distutils

My `foo_setup.py` looks like:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='pakcagename',
      version='2.0',
      description="Blahl blah",
      author="kimvais",
      url="http://www.google.com/",
      requires=['docopt',],
      py_modules=['api.fields',
                  'api.client',
                  'api._help',
                  'lib.https'],
      scripts=['bin/wrapper-script']
)
```

`python foo_setup.py build` works fine, but `python foo_setup.py sdist` gives:

```
running sdist
running check
warning: check: missing meta-data: if 'author' supplied, 'author_email' must be supplied too

warning: sdist: manifest template 'MANIFEST.in' does not exist (using default file list)

error: docs/someothermodule/html/html: No such file or directory
```

Why on earth does this happen?

**EDIT**: Adding a `MANIFEST.in` with following contents does not help:

```
prune *
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be because distutils first walks your whole tree of files before doing specific things for modules, C modules, package data and other data files.  Symlinks are not supported by distutils and can make it break if they are dangling.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO it is because when you are building a distribution.  When you do that you are expected to give **full** author details and documentation and since you are not supplying MANIFEST.in which details where such details are found it is trying to get away with a default file which is pointing to non-existent documentation.

Comment: distutils documentation does no mention whatsoever of `docs`, please explain what you mean.